How to get current User outside of Controller in another layer
In ASP.NET Core 6, I need to get the current user in service layer
This is code:
public class ServiceModel
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor accessor;

    public ServiceModel(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        this.accessor = accessor;
    }
}

But User is always Null:
var user = accessor.HttpContext?.User

Code in Program file:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<AppUser, AppRole>(options =>
{
    options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
    "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+/ ";
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
})
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<testContext>()
.AddUserManager<UserManager<AppUser>>()
.AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddCookie(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "MyAppCookie";
    options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
});

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

This the packages installed in Service Layer:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures


Where do you call HttpContext.SignInAsync method?

I call it in /Account/Login Controller

Hi @MrMustafa022, how do you call ServiceModel?
